# It it possible to use count with a function that matches an expression?

Tags: r, dplyr

Recently, I had the need of using a simple count function for a analysis workload.  The code was something like this:

```
count(datasetName, variableName %in% c("X330", "X331", "X332", "X333", "X334", "X335", "X336", "X337", "X338", "X339")
```

Looking at the code, I've been wondering if it is possible to just match the variables names using some sort of matching patterns. I my head, it would look like this:

count(datasetName, variableName %in% match("X33"))

From my research, dplyr contains matching functions, but those expect you to use select. I haven't been able to find how this would work with count.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sum` instead of `count` to get the count of logical vector where TRUE ->1 and FALSE -> 0

```
with(datasetName, sum(variableName %in% c("X330", "X331", "X332", "X333", "X334", "X335", "X336", "X337", "X338", "X339")))
```